# SendGrid C#, Is it recommended to create the SendGridClient object once or for each action

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Using SendGrid SDK for C#,
Is it recommended to create the SendGridClient object once, as a static prop.
or for each time I send a mail, create a new one.

Comment: A common approach is to use the [SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection) Nuget package to add the ISendGridClient interface as a service during startup. This will allow for configuration of the scope you require for your implementation.

An example of a transient scoped SendGrid implementation in a Net 6 Web API application can be found here: https://github.com/Davidmendoza1987/dotnet-sendgrid-examples